# How to find the number of connected componentes in two sets in order to show that they aren't homeomorphic.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

$A=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y^2=x^2 \}$ and $B=\{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2: y=x^2 \}$

I know that if I omit the point $(0,0)$. Then I have $4$ connected components for $A$ and $2$ connected components for $B$. And, a theorem gives me that because these number are different then these sets aren't homeomorphic.

My problem is: how to argue that $A$ has $4$ connected components and $B$ has $2$ connected components?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each case you can describe the components. For $A$ you get

$$\begin{align*}
&\{\langle x,x\rangle:x>0\},\\
&\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x>0\},\\
&\{\langle x,x\rangle:x<0\},\text{ and}\\
&\{\langle x,-x\rangle:x<0\}\,,
\end{align*}$$

and for $B$ you get $\left\{\left\langle x,x^2\right\rangle:x>0\right\}$ and $\left\{\left\langle x,x^2\right\rangle:x<0\right\}$. Each of these six sets is the image of a connected set under a continuous function, so each is connected. For instance, $\left\{\left\langle x,x^2\right\rangle:x>0\right\}$ is the image of the positive real axis under the continuous function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^2:x\mapsto\left\langle x,x^2\right\rangle$. And it’s straightforward to show each of the first four sets is a relatively open subset of $A$, while each of the last two is a relatively open subset of $B$.

Comment: Thanks!! I wrote these subsets but I was wondering how to argue, I mean how to write down a good mathmatics text.

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova: You’re welcome!

Comment: Hy, Brian. I have one more question. Why did you write the ordered pairs in the subsets using < and > ?

Comment: @VanyushaPavlova: Habit. It’s actually a standard notation for ordered pairs in set theory, and I prefer it, so I use it quite generally; parentheses are used for so many things that they’re a bit overloaded.